# Variables in commands executed by bash command line contain spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following directory structure.

```
# tree
.
├── 12 3.txt
└── 23.txt
```

I want to execute the following command.

```
# find -type f -name "*.txt" ! -path "./1 23.txt" ! -path "./12 3.txt"
```

Direct execution is normal.
I now need to use variables to splice the path.

```
# exclude='! -path "./1 23.txt" ! -path "./12 3.txt'
# echo $exclude
! -path "./1 23.txt" ! -path "./12 3.txt

# find -type f -name "*.txt" $exclude
find: paths must precede expression: `23.txt"'
```

But executing the command through variables will report an error.

It just like execute the following command.

```
# find -type f -name "*.txt" ! -path ./1 23.txt ! -path ./12 3.txt
find: paths must precede expression: `23.txt'
```

I've tried various single and double quotes around the variables, but it still doesn't work.
I want to know the reason and how to solve it.

Comment: The quotes in the variable are not parsed by the shell, and so you are basically creating a syntax error. The proper fix is to use an array variable, where you can store values while preserving their quoting. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050